# "re.sub" method with ".*"

Tags: python, regex, replace, python-re, python-3.9

I was using python `re` library and came across the following behavior.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(pattern=".*", repl="r", string="hello")
'rr'
```

As you can see, for the pattern `.*` and the replacement character(`r`)  `re.sub` method returning `rr`. But I was expecting the result as `r` because `.*` would match the entire string. Why is that?. I have also tested the same logic in Go but it was returning expected result.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`.*`)
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("Hello", "r")) // Will print `r`
}
```

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your observations](https://rextester.com/QEAG25003), at least not in Python.  Voting to close as a typo question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have tested this snippet in python 3.9(64 bit)

Comment: [Same result in Python 3.6.9](https://rextester.com/LTAZ3948).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Seems like it is returning correct result in 3.6 but not in 3.9

Comment: This was changed in version 3.7 IIRC, there's probably a regex question on this somewhere.. see https://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html for details

Comment: Beware of patterns that can match empty strings. The first match is a 5 character match starting a pos 0. The second match is a 0 character match starting at pos 5. A third match at position 5 is avoided as that would lead to an infinite loop.

Comment: Re "*Seems like it is returning correct result in 3.6 but not in 3.9*", Backwards. Matching at the end of the sting is perfectly legit. Consider `re.sub("$", "!", s)`

Comment: @ikegami Yea, My understanding was wrong :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should start explaining what's going on:

```
>>> re.sub("x?", "_", "hello")
'_h_e_l_l_o_'
```

At every position in the string `re.sub` tries to match `x?`. It succeeds, because `x?` can match the empty string, and replaces the empty string with `_`.

In a similar fashion, in the following

```
>>> re.sub(".*", "r", "hello")
'rr'
```

we have that `re.sub` tries to match `.*` in position 0, succeeds, and consumes the whole string. Then it tries to match at the end position, succeeds (matching the empty string) and replaces it with `r` again. The 'puzzling' behavior goes away if you disallow the empty match:

```
>>> re.sub(".+", "r", "hello")
'r'
```

---

In versions prior to Python 3.7 if `re.sub` consumed the whole string it would then not try to match at the end again, whereas in Python 3.7+ it does. To be more specific, quoting the documentation of `re.sub`:

> [Changed in version 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#:%7E:text=re.sub()%20now%20replaces%20empty%20matches): Empty matches for the pattern are replaced when adjacent to a previous non-empty match.

### Python 3.7+ (consistent behavior)

```
>>> matches = lambda r, s: [m.span() for m in re.finditer(r, s)]
>>> matches("x?", "x")
[(0, 1), (1, 1)]
>>> matches("x?", "y")
[(0, 0), (1, 1)]
>>> re.sub("x?", "r", "x")
'rr'
>>> re.sub("x?", "r", "y")
'ryr
```

### Python 3.6 (inconsistent behavior)

```
>>> matches("x?", "x")
[(0, 1), (1, 1)]
>>> matches("x?", "y")
[(0, 0), (1, 1)]
>>> re.sub("x?", "r", "x")
'r'
>>> re.sub("x?", "r", "y")
'ryr'
```

Comment: Great answer.  Might be good to include a reference that Python's regex engine in fact recently changed its behavior.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Added, with the relevant quote from the documentation.